# Is there a Rust build for aarch64-linux-android?

Tags: android, rust, rustup

Recently I got a new smartphone with fairly beefy specs, so wanting to play around with Rust on the go I installed Termux and tried to rustup-init. However, this fails:

```
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-aarch64-linux-android'
info: latest update on 2017-08-31, rust version 1.20.0 (f3d6973f4 2017-08-27)
error: target not found: 'aarch64-linux-android'
```

Is there another way to get a Rust environment on android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly rustup won't work on android.

You can manage to install cargo and rustc using Termux.

Also if you have rustup already installed, `rm .cargo` will remove the stub (which otherwise interferes with calling `cargo` or `rustc`).

Comment: Cool! I was able to install stable, however running it only gives me 'error: no default toolchain configured'.

Comment: Can you check the path of the rustc binary, it seems you still have a conflict with rustup. On my phone, the path is /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/rustc

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: This is very outdated... It's Pointless removed rustc, it's now in the main Repository. The Unstable Termux repository was deleted, and rustc-nightly is disabled due to an LLVM 12 incompatibility. You can still get Rustc-dev, but many packages will only build with experimental rustc-nightly features

Answer (score 3):

There is a `rust` package available via `pkg install rust`. It contains Cargo and appears to install packages successfully.

The package source is here: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/rust

Just a note: I had a binary failing to build during installation via Cargo due to libsqlite3-sys intermediate. This was solved by installing `binutils` package, which adds the archiver (ar) `aarch64-linux-android-ar`.
The ecosystem is not flawless yet.

Comment: how do you solve crate no std found?

Comment: @Rainb, I'm sorry, never ran into that issue. So far everything works great on the devices I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rustup inside of a prooted distro. Example using arch linux:

```bash
pkg update && pkg upgrade
pkg in proot-distro
proot-distro install archlinux
proot-distro login archlinux
# Ideally you should now setup a non-root user, but i'll omit this step for brevity
sudo pacman -Syu base-devel --needed
sudo pacman -Syu rustup # it's better to install rustup from repo
rustup toolchain default stable
rustup update
# Now you have a working rustup installation, but it can only be used from inside the distro. Anyway, that's better than nothing.
```

I personally don't use termux's environment at all and do everything inside the distro, so you might prefer to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use rustup directly in termux.  [guide](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/15851#issuecomment-1826439672). all rust related tools and frameworks will work too after patching them.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained -- links are acceptable to include but they should be supplemental: someone should still be able to be helped by the answer even if all its links break.